# How to write to an IBOutlet Label multiple times using stringValue

Tags: swift3

I am new to programming and Swift!
I have written a small program that downloads data from a web site. It has several phases to report progress (downloading, unzipping, cleaning the csv file, loading in array and saving). As files are large I have a label that reports the progress. The program works (Model)!

The problem comes from the ViewController when I update the label using stringValue in the updateUI function. 
The program crashes and I get the error. In the debugger I noticed that
statusLabel.stringValue is nil. 
However the crash does not occur at launch but when the operationStatus variable is updated. 
I guess the problem is related to optional but I do not understand why since I write to the label.
Any help/solution is welcomed. Thanks

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    // this variable monitors the status of the import
    var operationStatus: String = "import status" {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    // L 2008 - 2017 label
    //@IBOutlet weak var l2008Label: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var L2008: NSTextField!

    // import status label
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: NSTextField!{
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    // Import button
    @IBAction func importButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
        DataImport().importL2008()
    }


    // this method updates the import status Label
    private func updateUI() {
        statusLabel.stringValue = operationStatus

    }
  }
```

update: changed question title from "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0) after stringValue" to "How to write to an IBOutlet Label multiple times using stringValue".
If my understanding is correct, it looks like stringValue is set to Nil once it has been written. So I get the error when the program try to change the label the second time.

Comment: Did you check if you have an infinite loop since you are calling updateUI from statusLabel didSet method (that is called by updateUI itself when you change operationStatus) ?

Comment: You probably update the stringValue before `statusLabel` has been created. You can try doing: `statusLabel?.stringValue = operationStatus` in `updateUI` instead. Also you might need to call `updateUI` in `viewDidLoad()` too.

Comment: @matsoftware/ yes I checked the infinite loop. I have added several print debug point all along the program to verify that.

Comment: @ Ozgur I did the change to statusLabel?.stringValue. The program does not crash anymore, but the label does not get changed (statusLabel is still nil)

Answer (score 0):

Assignment to an optional variable will make a "Silent" read of the variable before performing the actual assignment.

If your statusLabel variable is not properly connected to your view controller in IB, you will not get an error until you make a reference to the variable (even for mere assignment). That would be the first thing to verify (IB outlet link).

BTW the didSet you have on the statusLabel variable will not be triggered by changing the stringValue but it may be triggered by the controller's initialization when the outlet link is made (you won't notice that if the outlet is not connected).

Comment: I am in a learning mode. I am nor quite sure I understand your post about "Silent" read and yoru last paragraph. Regarding the connection it looks like the Connection Inspector is referencing statusLabel correctly. Is that what you meant?

Comment: What I meant is that, in order to set a value to statusLabel.stringValue, the program will need to find the memory location and content of the value already there.  It statusLabel is nil, (and you didn't specify that unwrapping is optional by adding ?), then it will fait to reach the stringValue property.   What is strange however is that this would normally produce a different error message.  It is worth checking nontheless.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. What is strange is that  status.label is correctly  set to "import status" at launch. Then it is set to nil as soon as I click the import button.  I have seen a few posts with this issue. It may be a refresh IBOutlet issue. I am looking into that direction.